# Magento2 - UPS allowed methods not changing

Tags: magento2, admin, shipping, shipping-methods, ups

I am trying to select a few allowed shipping methods under UPS in the Magento 2 Admin.

I tried selecting the ones I want (e.g. UPS Standard, UPS Three-Day Select, UPS Next Day Air, etc) by holding the CTRL button and clicking each one. The ones I want change blue, and then when I click away they turn grey like they are supposed to. But when I click **Save Config**, it reverts back to selecting all the UPS Allowed Methods.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there anything in the console or logs? Have you tried a different combination of methods?

Comment: can you advise on version of magento so this can be recreated thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the store view isn't overwriting this setting with system value?

Comment: There is nothing in the console or logs. I've tried selecting just one, and multiple ones and none of the options save. Other settings save, but not the allowed methods. The version is 2.3.1. The System value check box is not marked

Answer (score 0):

The default system value was overwriting the store view and would not change in the store view *Default Config*. I had to change the store view to *My Store* and then select the **Allowed Methods** that I wanted to use for UPS